# Google Glass Provisioning - where can I find the QR Code?

Tags: android, google-glass, provisioning

I just received Google Glass Enterprise Edition 2. Right after I turn it on, the device boots up to a welcome screen with two options.

- Tap to proceed with provisioning.
- Swipe down to skip the Provisioning Wizard and continue with the standard boot process.

I should make a choice because:

> For security reasons, after you either complete or skip the
> Provisioning Wizard, you can't access the Provisioning Wizard again
> until you re-flash or factory reset the device.

As I understand it's better to select the Provisioning option and ccording to [this instruction](https://developers.google.com/glass-enterprise/guides/provisioning-and-configuration) I should:

> Scan the QR code that your MDM or custom agent provided.

I have 3 question:

1. What's the difference between these options, what are the advantages of Provisioning option?
2. Where can I find the QR code for the Provisioning option?
3. What is "MDM or custom agent"

Comment: While English may not be your first language, the link says "The QR code points to an Mobile Device Management (MDM) or custom agent who takes care of the entire device provisioning and configuration process." Searching on "mobile device management" should give results. Short version, MDM is software for controlling devices (password, restrict data) in a business environment. "Custom agent" may just a specialized app for provisioning (i.e. network isolated factory)..

Comment: @MorrisonChang The problem is that bo MDM and no provisioning apps were included in the package and no sign of it in the documentation. So does it mean that provisioning option intended for some specific use-cases when the glasses come with MDM solution, while if I'm just a new user-developer I just need to skip this step?

Comment: Correct. MDM allows for a level of remote control which makes sense in a business environment, and a Google Glass app for a client may need to integrate with client business MDM service. Unless you need to have a understanding of how Android does MDM, the information in those links are really for corporate developers. As an individual, just skip.